# Animated Div expand to full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  have three `div`s in my HTML. The end result I want is on click each div will expand smoothly to fill the entire screen (or the parent element which is full screen) and show additional information when the div is expanded (for example, on clicking on 'Resume' I need to show more content). I also want an exit button in the corner to close the expanded div.

I don't know what JavaScript or jQuery I need to incorporate. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ts932swL/5/) is a JSfiddle of my HTML and CSS

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page3">
    <div class="column" id="col1">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div>
        <a class="resumetitle" href=""><span></span>Education</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col2">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div>
        <a class="resumetitle" href=""><span></span>Work Experience</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col3">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div>
        <a class="resumetitle" href=""><span></span>Skills and Achievements</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.page3 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* W3C */
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 99.6vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.column {
    width: 42.5vh;
    height: 42.5vh;
    border: 1px dashed #dc143c;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.centeringelement {
    height: 45%;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dashed white;
}

.resumetitle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.column').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('large')
})
```

```css
.page3 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
  /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
  /* IE10 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
  /* W3C */
  border: 1px dashed yellow;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 99.6vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.column {
  background:orange;
  transition: .5s all;
  width: 42.5vh;
  height: 42.5vh;
  border: 1px dashed #dc143c;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 12.5%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.centeringelement {
  height: 45%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dashed white;
}
.resumetitle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  margin-top: 0;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.large {
  z-index:100000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page3">
  <div class="column" id="col1">
    <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Education</a>

  </div>
  <div class="column" id="col2">
    <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Work Experience</a>

  </div>
  <div class="column" id="col3">
    <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Skills and Achievements</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

How about this

```js
$('.column').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('large')
})
```

```css
.page3 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
    /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
    /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);
    /* W3C */
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 99.6vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.column {
    transition:.5s all;
    width: 42.5vh;
    height: 42.5vh;
    border: 1px dashed #dc143c;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.centeringelement {
    height: 45%;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dashed white;
}
.resumetitle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-top: 0;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.large {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:680px;
    min-width:680px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page3">
    <div class="column" id="col1">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Education</a>

    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col2">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Work Experience</a>

    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col3">
        <div class="centeringelement"></div> <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Skills and Achievements</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is real close. I changes the .large class to have a margin:0 and min-height:99.6vh to fully fill the screen. This works well for the first div (I notice it pushed the other divs down). However when I click on the other divs, they expand in-between the other two. How can i change this so that the other divs stay in place? (I just found an example of the effect I'm looking for: http://tympanus.net/Development/ButtonComponentMorph/index3.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.column').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'width':'100%','margin-left':'0px','margin-right':'0px'});
  });
});
```

```css
.page3 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* W3C */
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 99.6vh;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .column {
    width: 42.5vh;
    height: 42.5vh;
    border: 1px dashed #dc143c;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 1%;
    }

    .centeringelement {
    height: 45%;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    }

    .resumetitle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-top: 0;
    }
    span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page3">
                <div class="column" id="col1">
                    <div class="centeringelement"></div>
                    <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Education</a>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="col2">
                    <div class="centeringelement"></div>
                    <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Work Experience</a>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="col3">
                    <div class="centeringelement"></div>
                    <a class="resumetitle"><span></span>Skills and Achievements</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have made it expanding to the height of parent div and it also pushes your link down. Adjust the position of your link if you don't want it to be pushed down.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).on('click','.resumetitle',function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev().animate({
            height:$(this).parent('.column').height()
        },500);
    });
});
```